# How to record actions made on video by each user?

Tags: video, html5-video

I have some videos on a WordPress site, and I am looking for a way to record user actions or non-actions made by each user in a table looking way.

The list of actions to record are: Play/Pause/Stop/Replay/Move forward (action and seconds)/Move back (Action and seconds)

I hope to find a tool or a way to do this as it will be much help to produce videos that answer the needs of the users

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

One extensible way to do this, provided you are comfortable with using a Google solution, is to integrate Google Analytics with your Wordpress site.

Google analytics includes powerful reporting for video events and it is possible to export analytics data so you can manipukazre it or present it whatever way you want. You can find plugins to help integrate Google analytics into Wordpress, for example:

- https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-google-analytics-events/

There are also quite a few non Google Wordpress analytics plugins which cover video - search for 'Wordpress video analytics plugins', for example one which appears popular is (many others exist...):

- https://wordpress.org/plugins/clicky-analytics/